# Find the value of $\sum\binom{6n}{2k-1}(-3)^k$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Find the value of $\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\binom{6n}{2k-1}(-3)^k$.

**My working:**

\begin{align}
&  \sum\binom{6n}{2k-1}(-3)^k\\
=& \sum\binom{6n}{2k-1}(i\sqrt3)^{2k}\\
=& i\sqrt3\sum\binom{6n}{2k-1}(i\sqrt3)^{2k-1}\\
=& \frac{i\sqrt3[(1+i\sqrt3)^{6n}-(1-i\sqrt3)^{6n}]}{2}\\
=& \frac{i\sqrt3[(1+i\sqrt3+1-i\sqrt3)^{3n}((1+i\sqrt3-1+i\sqrt3)^{3n}]}{2}\\
=& \frac{i\sqrt3\cdot2^{3n}2^{3n}(i\sqrt3)^{3n}}{2} \\
=& \frac{2^{6n}(i\sqrt3)^{3n+1}}{2}
\end{align}

But the correct answer is $0$ and I can't figure out how one gets that. Moreover, I want to know what's wrong with my solution.

Comment: show that your sum has the value zero

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner isn't that the question? How do I do that?

Comment: Line 5 is incorrect: $(a\pm b)^k\ne a^k\pm b^k$ in general and here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$(1+i\sqrt 3)^{6n}-(1-i\sqrt 3)^{6n}=(re^{i\pi/3})^{6n}-(re^{-i\pi/3})^{6n}=r^{6n}(e^{i2\pi n}-e^{-i2\pi n})=r^{6n}(1-1)=r^{6n}\cdot 0$$

Comment: Okay I haven't studied complex numbers in such depth...can you elaborate?

Comment: @OsheenSachdev We knows, from Euler formula, that $$a+bi=r\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha)=re^{i\alpha}$$ from here, with the help of Pythagorean rule for rectangle triangles, we can know that $\alpha=\pi/3$

Comment: $=re^{i\alpha}$, how?

Comment: Okay, thank you so much...but I was wondering why my solution doesn't simplify to zero...any idea? (its a product of nonzero numbers...)

Comment: @OsheenSachdev I dont understand what you did in your fourth step... we have that $$(1+i\sqrt 3)^2=1-3+2i\sqrt 3=-2+i\sqrt3\neq 2$$

Comment: I just applied $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Comment: Oh right, that's wrong lol

Comment: @OsheenSachdev, I will add that we knows that $$r=|a+bi|=\sqrt{(a+bi)(a-bi)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$ In our case we have that $|1+i\sqrt3|=|1-i\sqrt3|=2=r$ (I deleted a previous comment accidentally).

Answer (score 2):

$\sum \binom{m}{2k-1}x^{2k-1}
+\sum \binom{m}{2k}x^{2k}
=\sum \binom{m}{k}x^k
=(1+x)^m
$.

$(1-x)^m
=\sum \binom{m}{k}(-1)^kx^k
$
so
$(1+x)^m+(1-x)^m
=\sum \binom{m}{k}x^k(1+(-1)^k)
=2\sum \binom{m}{2k}x^{2k}
$
and
$(1+x)^m-(1-x)^m
=\sum \binom{m}{k}x^k(1-(-1)^k)
=2\sum \binom{m}{2k-1}x^{2k-1}
$.

Therefore,
putting $x = i\sqrt{3}$
and $m = 6n$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum \binom{6n}{2k-1}(-3)^{k}
&=\sum \binom{6n}{2k-1}(i\sqrt{3})^{2k}\\
&=i\sqrt{3}\sum \binom{6n}{2k-1}(i\sqrt{3})^{2k-1}\\
&=\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}((1-i\sqrt{3})^{6n}-(1+i\sqrt{3})^{6n})\\
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

since
$(1-i\sqrt{3})^3
=(1+i\sqrt{3})^3
=-8
$
and
$(1-i\sqrt{3})^6
=(1+i\sqrt{3})^6
=64
$.

Similarly,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum \binom{6n}{2k}(-3)^{k}
&=\sum \binom{6n}{2k}(i\sqrt{3})^{2k}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}((1-i\sqrt{3})^{6n}+(1+i\sqrt{3})^{6n})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(64^n+64^n)\\
&=64^n\\
\end{array}
$